# Will Apple push notification feedback service report devices that call unregisterForRemoteNotifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

The documentation specifically states that the feedback service **will** report devices where the app has been uninstalled and **won't** report devices if the push merely expired.

My question is, will it report devices that have the app installed but the app called unregisterForRemoteNotifications (e.g. the user "signed out" of the app)?

Documentation:

> APNs has a feedback service that maintains a per-application list of devices for which there were failed-delivery attempts (that is, APNs was unable to deliver a push notification to an application on a device). Periodically, the provider should connect with the feedback service to see what devices have persistent failures so that it can refrain from sending push notifications to them.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW14

> The Apple Push Notification Service includes a feedback service to give you information about failed push notifications. When a push notification cannot be delivered because the intended app does not exist on the device, the feedback service adds that device’s token to its list. Push notifications that expire before being delivered are not considered a failed delivery and don’t impact the feedback service.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3

Answer (score 2):

My answer is `YES`, APNS does have this service in place along with its feedback service, mainly because the server triggering the push service will have to be notified back to stop sending push notification to the devices which have manually opted out of push notification service.

And since there is no way this information can reach back to the server directly except through APNS, APNS manages to hold this information to provide it back to the server.

Comment: Have you verified this in some way or is this just your assumption? I also hope that the answer is YES but I would like some concrete evidence.